Item is flickering when ':hover" pseudo class' 'top'/'TranslateY' is applied
I have the following piece of React code
      <div className="content-container">
        <div className="about-us">
          <h1>Why Fitness Tracker?</h1>
          <div className="info-tab1 info-tab">
            <img key="3" src={orange} alt="Fruit-3" className="fruit-3" />
            <p>Personalize</p>
          </div>
          <div className="info-tab2 info-tab">
            <p>Achieve</p>
          </div>
          <div className="info-tab3 info-tab">
            <img key="4" src={banana} alt="Fruit-4" className="fruit-4" />
            <p>Track</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="user-reviews">
          <div className="bottom-left-circle">
            <img key="1" src={strawberry} alt="Fruit-1" className="fruit-1" />
            <img key="2" src={apple} alt="Fruit-2" className="fruit-2" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

Each info-tab has applied BubbleUp animation as follows
animation: BubbleUp 1s ease-in-out forwards;

I have also added a :hover pseudo class that should move the item on the Y axis.
.info-tab:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -50px) !important;
}

The problem is that when I hover from upside down the element - everything is fine.
However, upon hovering from the bottom - it starts flickering.
I figured, or I think I do, that when I hover it goes up, then it goes out of range, e.g. the 'hover' is no longer active and it comes back, then it starts all over again rapidly.
I can't seem to find a 'best practice' in this scenario or even a simple solution.
I have tried to use TranslateY, top and translate(x, y), but the result is the same.

It's hard to decode this but general rule is if you move a button (or anything) if it has a hover or active state, make sure to leave something behind that is still clickable/hoverable.
You could use :before pseudo elements to do this or wrap it in a parent container and have the parent not move.
This may be the problem you are describing, the solution puts an invisible before pseudo in the -50px offset so something can still be :hover as the other stuff moves.
The below code while rather shows this rough concept.
button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

button:active:after {
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
}

While the CSS spec has changed a bit since the below demo/example:
https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/npERPW
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xG418MfI3g8

Wrap your .info-tab elements in a container & try this one :
.info-tab-container:hover .info-tab 
{   
transform: translate(0, -50px) !important; 
} 

